# is there any way to apply paging to ListView control in VB.NET win Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i am using **windows** form 2005 vb.net with **ListView** Control. now i want to apply **paging** to ListView,because i have to show lot of records in this control in page load. Please suggest me there is any way to apply paging to ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply paging at data source level through SQL (`TOP` and `LIMIT` clauses) or LINQ (`TAKE` and `SKIP` functions) and keep track of your current page in a global variable. You can then fill your ListView dynamically as user navigates between the pages.

### EXAMPLE

I don't know what your data source looks like, so I'm writing my code around a `List<Of Anything>`. Hopefully you can easily transform it according to the collection you're using:

Keep a Form-level variable and a global PageSize variable. Say:

```
Dim mPageNumber As Integer = 0
Const PAGE_SIZE As Integer = 25
```

Create buttons for moving to next/previous page on your form. Add the following code in their `Click` event:

```
mPageNumber += 1 '(or mPageNumber -= 1 in Previous button)
PopulateMyListView()
```

Create a new private procedure that updates your `ListView`'s contents:

```
Private Sub PopulateMyListView()
     MyListView.Clear()
     dim MyCurrentPageItems = MyItemsList.Skip(mPageNumber * PAGE_SIZE).Take(PAGE_SIZE)

     For Each item In MyCurrentPageItems
         MyListView.Items.Add(item.WhateverPropertyYouWantToShow)
     Next
End Sub
```

Call this procedure once in `Form_Load` too.

I have written the above code by hand, so there may be minor typos etc. Also, I haven't added any bound checks, which you should do on your end. For example, make sure `mPageNumber` doesn't get less than 0 or greater than the maximum number of pages. You can find the maximum number of pages by simply dividing the total number of items by `PAGE_SIZE`.

Comment: thanks for Replay, I am new to this, if you have any sample please post, i hope that will help me.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server then you might want to consider using LINQ to SQL or, preferably, Entity Framework.  You can then `Skip` and `Take` to get a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by dotNET, the `ListView` won't do the paging part for you so that's going to have to be implemented in your data access code.

As for displaying pages of data, if you want it to be seamless to the user then you can look at virtualising the `ListView`.  If you're interested in that then start with the documentation for the `VirtualMode` property and go from there.

Otherwise, you could just provide `Button`s to move forward and back that will discard the current contents and and load a whole new page, which would be simpler but maybe not quite as nice for the user.

Comment: This is a good answer!